# android json object can not be convert to jsonarray?

Tags: android

I am getting `Exception` that json object cannot be converted to json array..,when I am showing values from server, here is my code. Please help me.

```
 if(respons!=null){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(respons);
        JSONArray post=jsonObj.getJSONArray("List of image URLs");
        for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
            String values = post.getString(i);

            _issueList.add(values);

        }
 }
```

Here is my json exception at this output

```
 {
    "message": [
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389346961Quincredible_1-
2.png",
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389346977Quincredible_1-
3.png",
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389346996Quincredible_1-
4.png",
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389347016Quincredible_1-
5.png",
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389347039Quincredible_1-
6.png",
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389347052Quincredible_1-
7.png",
        "http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/upload\/1389347062Quincr32.png"
    ]
}
```

This data is coming from server. I don't know why this error is occurring, my images are not showing and moving.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: he he new day new questions great

Comment: hello may i help you any more?? then plz upvote and ri8 tik

Comment: sure sir,,.i will tell.thanku

Comment: then plz upvote and mark as ri8 and dont call me sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to:

```
 if(respons!=null){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(respons);
        JSONArray post=jsonObj.getJSONArray("message");
        for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
            String values = post.getString(i);

            _issueList.add(values);

        }
 }
```

key for your json array is `message` not `List of image URLs`

Comment: if(respons!=null){
     try{
      JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(respons);
      JSONObject post=jsonObj.getJSONObject("List of image URLs");
      JSONArray array= post.getJSONArray("message");
      for(int i =0;i<array.length();i++){
       String values = array.getString(i);

       _issueList.add(values);

Answer (score 1):

```
if(respons!=null){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(respons);
                    JSONArray post=jsonObj.getJSONArray("message");
                    for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
                        String values = post.getString(i);

                        _issueList.add(values);

                    }
```

Comment: it's very nice to tell OP what you changed that make better understand

Comment: digveshji ,that is not r8..,it is giving me no value

Answer (score 0):

Change your below line in which you need to get the arraylist of `message` where you have written wrong key. Other code is fine.

```
JSONArray post=jsonObj.getJSONArray("List of image URLs");
```

Change it to

```
 JSONArray post=jsonObj.getJSONArray("message");
```

As you are getting only the `JSONArray` in your response there is not need of `JSONObject` in your code.

You can parse your array as below which will directly give you an array :

```
     try{
        JSONArray post=new JSONArray(respons);
        for(int i =0;i<post.length();i++){
            String values = post.getString(i);

            _issueList.add(values);

        }
```